# How to fail command if zero or more than one line in output

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Let's say I have a command like

`git log --some-options`

and I expect it to produce *exactly one* line so I could feed it to `xargs`, like `git log --some-options | xargs git branch --all --contains`

how do I make sure that, when `git log` command produces 0, or more than one, lines, then my command fails and `git branch` never gets called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not running the command when there's no input to `xargs` is easy - it has the `-r` option for that. For most uses of xargs I've seen, you *should* be using this option.

Not running the command for more than one line of input can be trickier, but can be done by using, say, awk, to print the input only if there's one line:

```
... | awk 'END { if (NR == 1) print }'
```

For example:

```
% seq 1 10 | awk 'END { if (NR == 1) print }'
% # no output
% seq 1 | awk 'END { if (NR == 1) print }'
1
```

Then you can combine the two:

```
git log --some-options | awk 'END { if (NR == 1) print }' | xargs -r git branch --all --contains
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wc -l` like this:

```
[[ $(git log --some-options | wc -l) -eq 1 ]] && git log --some-options | xargs git branch --all --contains
```

The condition `[[ $(git log --some-options | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]` checks if the number of lines in the command `git log --some-options` is exactly 1, and if it's true runs the command after `&&` (logical AND in bash).

Comment: I was thinking of this but it implies running the command twice, which I would rather avoid...

Comment: Yes, muru's solution is actually better in several ways! ^^ 